# ionic-app-script fails on build - Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli/ngtools2'

Tags: ionic3, node-modules

Only when I'm building my app to production I got the error `Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli/ngtools2'` in the `build` step from `ionic-app-script`, after `ionic cordova run android --prod`

I have in my `package.json` file the dependence `"@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.4",` and looking in my `node_modules` folder I can see `@angular/compiler-cli/ngtools2.js`

Why ionic-app-script can't find it?

Full error:

```
$ ionic cordova run android --prod
> ionic-app-scripts build --prod --platform android
[10:08:45]  ionic-app-scripts 3.2.2 
[10:08:45]  build prod started ...
[10:08:45]  clean started ...
[10:08:45]  clean finished in 24 ms
[10:08:45]  copy started ...
[10:08:45]  deeplinks started ...
[10:08:45]  deeplinks finished in 84 ms
[10:08:45]  ngc started ...
[10:08:47]  ionic-app-script task: "build" 
[10:08:47]  Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli/ngtools2' 
Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli/ngtools2'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:206:90
    at <anonymous>
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ionic-app-scripts.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved that problem updating my dev dependencies

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.2",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your `@angular/compiler-cli` version. It should be matched with angular other dependencies. In my case, it version of CLI higher.

```
"@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^10.0.4",
"@angular/core": "5.2.11",
```

So, I downgrade it.

```
"@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11"
```

And it work perfectly.